# How do i redirect a list of IP addresses to a command line function?

Tags: bash, command

I want to see what countries are trying to access my VPS.  I have installed a tool called "goiplookup", which was forked from another effort called "geoiplookup".  If I type this at the command line:

```
goiplookup 8.8.8.8
```

It returns this:

US, United States

So I figured out how to get a list of IPs that are trying to access my server by using this:

```
sudo grep "disconnect" /var/log/auth.log | grep -v COMMAND | awk '{print $9}'
```

Which gives a long list of IPs like this:

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

I cannot figure out how to get this list of IPs to be processed by the "goiplookup" tool.  I tried this:

```
sudo grep "disconnect" /var/log/auth.log | grep -v COMMAND | awk '{print $9}' | goiplookup
```

but that did not work.  I also tried with no luck:

```
sudo grep "disconnect" /var/log/auth.log | grep -v COMMAND | awk '{print $9}' | xargs -0 goiplookup
```

Comment: Are you saving these IPs to a file or are you trying to process them as you get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo grep "disconnect" /var/log/auth.log | grep -v COMMAND | awk '{print $9}' | sort | uniq | xargs -n 1 goiplookup
```

- I added `| sort | uniq` to ensure each IP only appears once
- and `xargs -n 1` so that each found IP is processes by `goiplookup`

Comment: In many `sort` variants (such as GNU `sort`), `sort -u` deduplicates the output.

Comment: @Fatp `sort -u` is POSIX

Comment: You should use `xargs -n 1`, because `geoiplookup` allows only one IP per invocation. If multiple IPs are passed, only the last one will be used.

Comment: Thank, that works with the xargs -n 1

Answer (score 1):

I would put it into a file and make a small utility to parse it:

```
sudo grep "disconnect" /var/log/auth.log | grep -v COMMAND | awk '{print $9}' | sort -u > ./file.txt

cat ./file.txt | while read -r line; do
      temp$(echo $line)

      goiplookup $temp
done
```

This will read through the file one line at a time and execute the goiplookup with each IP.

Comment: Thank, that's what I did.  That worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo grep disconnect /var/log/auth.log | awk '!/COMMAND/ && !seen[$0]++ {system("geoiplookup \""$9"\""}
```

- Note that `geoiplookup` only allows one IP per invocation.
- The whole thing can be done in awk, but using grep allows the rest to be run unprivileged.
- Consider whether `grep -w` (match whole word) is appropriate, and in awk you can do a similar thing with `!/(^|[^[:alnum:]_])COMMAND($|[^[:alnum:]_])/`.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a shell script, which works.

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t array < <(sudo grep "disconnect" /var/log/auth.log | grep -v COMMAND | awk '{print $9}'  | sort | uniq)
for ip in "${array[@]}"
do
   :
 country=$(/usr/local/bin/goiplookup -c $ip)
 echo "$ip $country"
done
```

Comment: You should edit that and format your code properly for SO.  Edit, select the text and press the `{}` icon.